# Number of listwidget columns in iconmode when starting app vs switching from listmode

Tags: python, pyside2, qlistwidget

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Slot
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QMenuBar, QMenu, QListWidget, \
    QListWidgetItem, QListView, QDesktopWidget, \
    QAction

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.listview = QListWidget()

        self.menubar = QMenuBar()

        self.menuView = QMenu("View")
        self.actionList = QAction("List Mode", self)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionList)
        self.actionList.triggered.connect(self.listMode)
        self.actionGrid = QAction("Grid Mode", self)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionGrid)
        self.actionGrid.triggered.connect(self.gridMode)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.menuView)
        self.bodyLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.desktop = QDesktopWidget()
        self.listview_width = self.desktop.availableGeometry(self).width()*0.7
        self.listview.setMaximumWidth(self.listview_width)
        self.listview.setMovement(QListView.Movement.Static)
        self.listview.setResizeMode(QListView.ResizeMode.Fixed)
        self.listview.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.listview.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridMode()

        for i in range(50):
            item = QListWidgetItem(self.listview)
            item.setText("item"+str(i))
            self.listview.addItem(item)

        self.bodyLayout.addWidget(self.listview)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.menubar)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.bodyLayout)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    @Slot()
    def listMode(self):
        self.listview.setViewMode(QListView.ListMode)

    @Slot()
    def gridMode(self):
        self.listview.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)

    def run(self):
        self.show()
        app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MainWindow()
    window.run()
```

If you run this, switch to list mode and back to grid mode. The initial number of columns in grid mode shows less columns than subsequent switches to grid mode. How would I make it look the same as the subsequent switches initially? Post is mostly code because of qt boilerplate needed to reproduce this problem.

EDIT: Solved. Changed

```
self.listview.setResizeMode(QListView.ResizeMode.Fixed)
```

to

```
self.listview.setResizeMode(QListView.ResizeMode.Adjust)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: The MRE must be in your question as a text, not in an external link that can be broken making your question useless

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Changed

```
self.listview.setResizeMode(QListView.ResizeMode.Fixed)
```

to

```
self.listview.setResizeMode(QListView.ResizeMode.Adjust)
```